# File Sorting Based on Similar File and Folder Names

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-ise

Im still generally new to powershell, and I am trying to create a program that will take files based on their name, and move them into folders that have a similar name but not exactly the same.
For example, Lets say I have 3 files, Apples.txt, Grapes.txt, and Oranges.txt. And I want to move them into corresponding folders, ApplesUSA, GrapesNY, OrangesFL.
I could just hard code it using a loop and a If-Then Statement. i.e If Apples.txt exists move to ApplesUSA. But I want it to be dynamic, so if other files and folders are added later I dont have to update the code. Is there a way to write a statement that would say if FileA and FolderB are similar in name (both contain apples in the name somewhere) then move fileA to FolderB and so on.
Any help appreciated. Thanks!!!!

Comment: In PowerShell, `Get-Help About_Comparison_Operators`

Comment: If you can clearly describe the pattern, e.g. "the full filename matches the start of the folder name", then yes, ranging from easy to exhaustive-search of every overlapping character set. If there isn't a pattern simpler than understanding English to make the connection, then https://xkcd.com/1425/

Comment: Well id say 80 percent of the files are dead on matches to the folder where they will be moving to. Thats the easy part, its the other couple of files that are the problem, but the pattern is the same. Apples.txt moving to folder ApplesUSA. Guess the main question is how do I do a comparison that could pick up on the start of the filename?

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
$PathWithFile="C:\temp\Test"
$PathWithDir="C:\temp\Test"

Get-ChildItem $PathWithFile -file -Filter "*.txt" | %{
$CurrentFile=$_
$Dirfounded=Get-ChildItem $PathWithDir -Directory | where {$_ -match $CurrentFile.BaseName} | select FullName -First 1
if ($Dirfounded -ne $null)
{
   move-Item $CurrentFile.FullName -Destination $Dirfounded.FullName -WhatIf
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A oneliner similar to @Esperento's

```
gci *.txt -af|%{$File=$_.FullName;gci "$($_.BaseName)*" -ad|%{Move $File -Dest $($_.FullName) -whatif}}
```

The verbose version:

```
PushD "X:\path\to\base\folder"
Get-ChildItem *.txt -File | ForEach-Object{
  $File = $_.FullName
  Get-ChildItem "$($_.BaseName)*" -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Move-Item $File -Destination $_.FullName -whatif
  }
}
PopD
```

Both versions require PowerShell V3 for the `-File` and `-Directory` parameters (and their aliases `-af`/`-ad`) This can be substituted by an additional `|Where-Object{ $_.PSIsContainer}` respective `| Where-Object{!$_.PSIsContainer}`